# What do you call the 12-24 hour aspect of a timestamp? (not format)

Tags: single-word-requests, time

Is there a word to denote whether the timestamp is in 24 hour format or 12 hour format?

Programmers usually call it format, but format can apply to the entire timestamp.

Wikipedia calls them conventions, but convention is also used for the entire timestamp.

Comment: "12/24 clock" is in use in programming and seems unambiguous.

Answer (score 1):

I will go out on a limb and say there isn't one: it's *24-hour format* or *12-hour format.*

Generally, English is an efficient language in that it re-uses words; it doesn't define more words than it needs. Thus English would *describe the format,* it doesn't have a word *for* the format until the description becomes so cumbersome or used so often that a shorter way of expressing it is needed.

Thus we don't have a word for a hard-back book (even the single word *hard-back* or *hardback* is really an adjective with *book* being omitted as understood). We don't have a word for *brilliant white* paint as opposed to *white* or *off-white.* Even a *queue* is often qualified as a *queue of people.* We don't have a word for *roof-tile* as opposed to *wall-tile.*

An exception which proves the rule might be *telephone:* that word has been associated with desk-bound phone apparatus for so long that *mobile phone* (that is, an adjective qualifying *phone*) was needed, and now the concept is so ubiquitous that simply *mobile* suffices.

Some of these specific examples don't hold for American English (which has *line* for *queue* and *cell* for *mobile*) but the general principle does. It's simply how the language works.

Comment: In the 1950's when the 24-hour-clock was very seldom used in Britain it was often referred to as "the Continental clock" or "Continental time". The first place I ever encountered it was on a visit to France -  used in everyday speech, where perhaps, even now, it isn't in Britain. But now it is in use almost everywhere for things like rail timetables etc. I remember my French teacher explaining it to my class at school.

Comment: 24 hour time is also called *military time*. I think that started as an American term. But I don't think having a name for one format helps us come up with a term encompassing both, unfortunately (@WS2)

Answer (score 1):

Timestamp usually consist of Date, Time and Timezone(like UTC, IST).
Eventhough the term is coined as `timestamp`, this isn't something which is completely related to time alone.

so,

you can better term `timestamp format` to refer different timestamp formats and

you can term `time formats` to refer 24hr format and 12hr format

Comment: The problem with using your own definitions in situations like this is that you then have to ensure that everyone reading your documentation is aware of the specific meanings. Most people reading "time formats" will not immediately be thinking in terms of 12- or 24-hour.